# XPath check for attribute and show the value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to check a bunch of `.xml` files for a specific permission, which is an attribute. If there is such a permission attribute i have to find out which value the attribute has.

this is my code which produces `NullPointerExceptions`:

```
public static void checkXmlPermissions(String path)
    {
        FileInputStream file;
        try                                                                                                 
        {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
                                                                                                            //XPath initialisieren;
            DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();                          

            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


            String expression ="//*[@permission]";                                                                          //Expression;
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                String match = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                System.out.println(match);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
```

I guess my mistake is the `NodeList` but I can´t find a solution by my own.

Comment: what line causes the exception? can you show example input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
String match = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

to:

```
String match = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
```